# My Selenium script is failing to pick information without displaying any error message

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I have this selenium script to scrape links like [this](https://www.giffgaff.com/mobile-phones/apple/iphone-12-5g/refurbished) and [this](https://www.giffgaff.com/mobile-phones/samsung/samsung-galaxy-s21-plus-5g/refurbished). It is configured to scrape once each day. The script I used worked for a day or two. Now it does not yield any output in my csv file.
I changed my IP to check if that was the problem, but it still gave me nothing in the csv file.
I tried using geckodriver but it still gave the same response. Also, note that there is **no error message** in the terminal to indicate if there is a problem.
**Any comment will be greatly appreciated**.

Here's my script:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait 
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
import csv

options1 = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
    # options1.add_argument('--start-maximized')
    options1.add_experimental_option('excludeSwitches', ['enable-logging'])
    # options1.add_argument("window-size=1920x1480")
    # options1.add_argument("disable-dev-shm-usage")
    # options1.add_argument("--headless")
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=Service(ChromeDriverManager().install()), options=options1)
    

    filename = "data.csv"
    with open(filename, 'w', encoding='utf-8', newline='') as file:
        writer = csv.writer(file)
        writer.writerow([ "URL", "MODEL", "STORAGE", "COLOUR", "GRADE", "PRICE"])

    List_open = open("links.txt")
    read_list = List_open.read()
    line_in_list = read_list.split("\n")

    for url in line_in_list:
        page = driver.execute_script("window.open('{}','_blank');".format(url))
        handles = driver.window_handles
        main_window = driver.current_window_handle
        driver.switch_to.window(handles[-1])
        sleep(5)

        try:
            wait=WebDriverWait(driver,10)
            cookies = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH,"//div[@class='cbot-layout--2column cbot-layout--right cbot-layout--ctas']/a[1]/span[1]")))
            cookies.click()
        except:
            pass
        
        sleep(5)
        model_name = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH,"//h1[@class='gg-u-text-shout']"))).text
        try:
            storage_container = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH,"//div[@class='MemorySelector__MemoryContainer-jkajbs-0 jKQdwX gg-u-mb-small']/fieldset/ol/li/label")))
            for item in storage_container:
                size = item.text
                item.click()
                sleep(2)
                colour_container = driver.find_elements("xpath","//fieldset[@data-testid='colour-selector']/ol/li/label/span")
                for c in colour_container:
                    colour = c.text
                    grade_price = driver.find_elements("xpath","//div[@class='gg-u-pb-medium']/fieldset/ol/li")
                    for g in grade_price:
                        grade = g.find_element("xpath", ".//label/span[1]").text
                        price = g.find_element("xpath", ".//label/span[2]/span").text
                        
                        # print(url + "," + model_name + "," + size + "," + colour + "," + grade + "," + price.strip() + "\n")

                        with open(filename, 'a', encoding='utf-8') as file:
                            file.write(url + "," + model_name + "," + size + "," + colour + "," + grade + "," + price.strip() + "\n")
        except:
            with open(filename, 'a', encoding='utf-8') as file:
                    file.write(url + "," + model_name + "," + "None" + "," + "None" + "," + "Out of Stock" + "," + "Out of Stock" + "\n")
      
        driver.close()
        driver.switch_to.window(main_window)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your links are protected by Google reCAPTCHA its blocking your script. You should use some Captcha Solver APIs or you should create own deep learning model for this.

Comment: Thanks @Emre. Any idea which of the captcha solver APIs will be best for this specific use case?

Comment: There many of them usually price is 1000 request like 2-3 dollar and solve time for this depend the company. Also you can check this [link](https://medium.com/analytics-vidhya/cracking-recaptchas-with-cnns-and-transfer-learning-edc26ab675ec) for if you want to build your own solver.